# Magento 2 Order notification email sent after 3 hours of creating order?

Tags: email, magento-enterprise-2

I transferred my website to another hosting company. Now When I create an order, I got the notification email 3 hours later, while it was instant email. What may have changed after the transfer?

Comment: can you please check server cron is configured correctly. 
otherwise the problem is in server. check mail.log is in queue up.

Answer (score 0):

Try again and run this from root of magento directory:

```
bin/magento cron:run
```

If your email is received instantly then there may be an issue with cron jobs check that cron is set correctly, guide for this is here:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I will try it and get back to you